# Send mail using Gmail from php in localhost

Tags: php, gmail, phpmailer

I'm already know how to use phpmailer but I can't send mail which are using Gmail (I have in phpmailer all the configuration done like port, server name, etc) because it are using OAuth 2.0 and I already get my client id an all that but I'm getting this error:

```
 400. That’s an error.

Error: invalid_scope

Some requested scopes were invalid. {invalid=[email@gmail.com]}

Learn more

Request Details
```

when I try to connect to the server from the URL so what I must to do about that?

this is the file which I have the codes, I'm going to change some character to keep this private, I hope that you sand me with this some example how to use it.

copy and paste in a noteblock to have this more clear.

```
{
  "private_key_id": "c6ffd46f1@@@@@@@@@@@50@@@@@@62b620526a",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIICdwIBADA@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@wggJdAgEAAoGBAJYjqzxsw9z9kdp5\ngjuqZz0vVuad574M6fTlFcLp3HdPg8y2hxl2hzW+lZPCWFDUgRgmJEWAR1Qf40ZB\nTm4FwD4mN7/YmExzjVTJ9sPHkf@@@@@@@@o7VincKg5RddvYML95Vzzz0\n1ft@@@@@@@@@@@e0CKuWeIXDKbJVAgMBAAECgYBBc4dArkGsYzZkQbhOfnjHKY3+\ntzPB@@@@@@@@@@@IDcztkeyti2M3EAu8MTXf1N9yAhQk134RxpxkQJqPbk\na5lxv+euyq@@@@@@@@@@iTyKglke8AgR3tXFWcFT1u0p6VeC3uQOskFEO4jNS\nNBbuOcVn/LbyNoB4+QJB@@@@@@@@@@@wU81o36dLz/Ad7hl4yqdWcmotEe38j1\nWa/mBBHGMm+XJFLnfnde/KNeY8a@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@QQDA8Ej7Ho6whqAiP3d5\nO4@@@@@@@@@@@@3VCzPipDjYzZjvojqz3WRW1pTvAvRcmWWCSJSUOV2FI\npENvAk@@@@@@@@@@@@@jojJJ59QokIYFDlALIP4FiDUVnTKrbZ1JdsqXcRmm\nTzJuVi@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@Ihh91BmYFwTBfvsbhUJ8At2IqkpP\nemKr2hbUMs4yTd1IT@@@@@@@J+@@@@@@@@P8CQHVWlZPm\nm7oV9484A8NHT@@@@@@@@@@@@MpUlAbk37C45gU4xFhp1MSvNsNiO\nquDr@@@@@kitgIc\u003d\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "56@@@@@@@@5@@63-3tummk4ie@@@@@@@@@@@@fajni0sun19n@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "56@@@@@@5@@63-3tu@@@@@@@@nlejapn5fajni0sun19n.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "type": "service_account"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [pear mail library](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/download)

```
// Pear Mail Library
require_once "Mail.php";

$from = '<from.gmail.com>';
$to = '<to.yahoo.com>';
$subject = 'Hi!';
$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

$headers = array(
    'From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject
);

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => '465',
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => 'johndoe@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'passwordxxx'
    ));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo('<p>' . $mail->getMessage() . '</p>');
} else {
    echo('<p>Message successfully sent!</p>');
}
```

I got it from [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2748837/)

Comment: i was using wamp and install it was a little complicate so i just install xampp that already have pear and i did it, thx.. (wamp + phpmailer, seems that doesnt work)